# Link Email to Google Task

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, task

I am creating tasks from email similar to [this](http://www.pipetree.com/qmacro/blog/2011/10/automated-email-to-task-mechanism-with-google-apps-script/). In addition I want to link the corresponding message, just like it happens when you create a task from email manually.

This example creates as task with the correct title and due date, but no link to the message is incorporated.

```
//new Task
var newTask = Tasks.newTask();

//set Title
newTask.setTitle("Task Title");

//set DueDate
var dueDate = new Date();
newTask.setDue = (dueDate.toISOString());

//set Link
var taskLink = Tasks.newTaskLinks()
.setType("email")
.setLink("https://url-to-my-message");
newTask.setLinks(taskLink);

//insert task
newTask = Tasks.Tasks.insert(newTask, "MyListID");
```

I noted that the links property is readonly (why???). Any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like at the moment, there's no way to link an email to a task via the API.  At the Tasks API level, it states that the `links` parameter is read-only, and since Google Apps Scripts use the API, there's no way for them to set this property.  Sad, I know.  You'll probably have to wait until they move the Tasks API out of "Experimental" status.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/v1/reference/tasks#resource

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around to this issue, which I have been exploring.

Please note that the answer given by LukeGT is correct, and my answer below is work around to give you the ability to have the same functionality which currently Google has not exposed.

For those who want to know more about the whole concept of creating Google Tasks form a set of emails, I recommend this [excellent tutorial](http://pipetree.com/qmacro/blog/2011/10/automated-email-to-task-mechanism-with-google-apps-script/) which got my ball rolling on this topic.

The basic idea is to place the email link into the Task title rather than as the above 'email' links.

To make it a little more concise, I use the Google Url Shortener service so as to render the Task title shorter.  Works fine for me, here is the code... (please note that you can get the link to a mail via this [example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#getPermalink%28%29), you'll also need to authorise the Url Shortener service).

```
var emailURL = "https://url-to-my-message";
var url = UrlShortener.Url.insert({
  longUrl: emailURL
});
var taskDetails = {
  title: 'My email task: '+url.id,
  notes: "Check the link for details",
};
Tasks.Tasks.insert(taskDetails, "MyListID");
```

and here is what it looks like... ( i.stack.imgur.com/hZWHF.png, sorry, but can't post images as yet)

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to see how Aurovrata's 'work around' would integrate directly into the gmail tasks solution linked in twjstoll's post, the following has worked well for me.

```
// Construct the url string
// Shorten the URL
var emailURL = "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/"+thread.getId();
var url = UrlShortener.Url.insert({
  longUrl: emailURL
});

// Insert the task   
addTask_(taskTitle + " " + url.id, taskNote, TASKLIST);
```

Thanks to all those who helped.